# spectral theory of Laplacian on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Can you describe the spectrum of the Laplacian
$ \Delta : H^2(\mathbb R^n) \subset L^2(\mathbb R^n) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R^n)$?

I am interested for which values $z \in \mathbb C$ the equation

$\Delta u + z u = f$

has a solution $u \in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. I *think* that the point spectrum is empty, but is every $z$ in the resolvent set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Fourier transform.

Taking the Fourier transform  we see that  is equivalent to 
$$(-\lvert\xi\rvert^2 +z)\hat{u}=\hat{g}, $$
which has the unique formal solution 
$$\tag{2}\hat{u}=-\frac{\hat{g}}{-z+ \lvert\xi\rvert^2}.$$

Now you have to prove that this formal solution make sense in $H^2$ if and only if $z\leq 0$.

Comment: It seems to me that this solution would be in $H^2$ if $\text{Im}(z)\neq 0$.